# multi boot win xp pro 32 bit, win 7 pro 64 bit, ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: dual-boot

I'm a complete novice to Linux, so step by step instructions for me would be greatly appreciated.

As the header states I'm attempting to setup those 3 OS's specifically with multi-boot. I've used paragon to setup 3 primary partitions on a 1T drive. 2 partitions are set to 200 GB and the remaining drive is set to the balance of space on the drive. One of the 200 GB drives will be used for Ubuntu.

I've done some reading on multi-boot here and in other places, but frankly I find it convoluted and certainly nothing advising of my specific o/s strategy. My reading advises me to setup any Windows OS first then setup Ubuntu as the final install, but everywhere I read people have had nightmares with the boot loader. I keep reading about grub 2 and I have no idea what grub 1 or 2 is or how to initialize it or use it or what its purpose is. (I know you're going to tell me to read up on it, but as you know, reading up it will lead to more questions and more reading and I'll never get to actually installing the OS's).

So bottom line is I have two questions:

1. Am I better off using a 3rd party boot manager for all 3 OS's?
2. Are there easy step by step instructions for multi-boot systems for the strategy I have described?

Comment: I'm going to repeat what you have read: install both of the Windows OS'es first, and install Ubuntu last.

Comment: Why XP, since so obsolete? But use grub. Install both Windows in primary partitions formatted NTFS. Move boot flag to each before install and then from grub you can directly boot both. Window only installs all boot files to one active (boot flagged) partition and then you can only boot the one Windows from grub and from Windows then choose which one you want.

Answer (score 0):

Starts with the live-cd of Ubuntu. 
Loading is complete and opens a terminal running on it:

```
sudo su
gparted
```

Loaded gparted, you choose the disk dev/sda. 
Creates a new table of msdos partition. 
Applies the changes. 
Then creates in the unpartitioned space: 
A primary partition, fat 32 file system of 500 megs. 
A primary partition ntfs file system of 80 gigs. 
A primary partition ntfs file system of 120 gigs. 
An extended partition the rest free.
A logical partition within the extended file system ext4 of 120 gigs.
A logical partition within the extended file system exchange (swap) of 12 gigas.
A logical partition within the extended file system ext4 of 120 gigs.
A logical partition within the extended ntfs file system, free from the rest. 
Applies the changes.
Starts the installation of Windows XP, choose the first NTFS partition 80 gigas, format it, completed the installation: 
Starts the installation of Windows 7, choose the second ntfs partition of 120 gigs, format it,completed the installation verifies that Windows 7 allows you to start with both operational, any doubt consultation to a Microsoft forum. 
Starts the installation of Ubuntu. 
When you get to choose manual custom partitioning.
Selects the first logical partition ext4 40 gigs for /.
Selects the third partition logic ext4 of 120 gigs for /home.
The GRUB on the MBR of /dev/sda.